# Why does a reference to a C/C++ DLL project from a C# class library project break in Visual Studio when building the solution?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I am in the process of creating a library to be used in Windows desktop applications. The core part of the library will be a C/C++ DLL that can be used in Win32 applications or other C/C++-based apps. I'll just call it `libtest.dll` for easy referencing here. I also want to make it available to Windows Forms applications (C#), so I am creating a C# class library (DLL) as a wrapper around the C/C++ library using P/invoke (`DllImport`) to call into the C/C++ code. I'll refer to this library as `Test.dll`.

Additionally, I have a Windows Forms project set up in Visual Studio for testing that depends on the C# class library project. The C# class library depends on the C/C++ library project. However, for `Test.dll` to find `libtest.dll` (in the `DllImport` statements), `libtest.dll` needs to either be in the same directory as `Test.dll` or in one of the DLL search paths in the system.

To make this easy when debugging in Visual Studio, I thought adding the `libtest.dll` project as a reference to the `Test.dll` project would automatically copy `libtest.dll` into the output directory of the `Test.dll` project. When I add the reference and then build the solution, the reference ends up broken and the `libtest.dll` file is not copied into the output directory of `Test.dll`.

When I add the reference to the `Test.dll` project in Visual Studio, the properties of the reference look fine:

- "Copy Local" is set to `True`
- The path is correct
- "Resolved" is `True`

After building, however, the reference itself has a warning icon on it, and the path is now empty and "Resolved" is `False`. Any idea why, or how to fix this? How do I set up the project reference between these two library projects so the C/C++ DLL gets copied into the output directory of the C# class library project? I have verified that the build order of the two projects is correct: first `libtest` then `Test`.

Comment: That is expected, MSBuild can't know the EXE project has a dependency on this DLL, it does not appear as an assembly reference in Test.dll.   A basic workaround is to add it to the EXE project and set its Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer.  Do note that it is very odd that you could add libtest.dll as a reference in the first place, VS should have complained about it because it is not a COM server or .NET assembly.  Sounds like it temporarily lost its marbles.  If this is a recent VS2017 version then you can file the bug report with Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm on VS2015. And as a matter of fact, it does complain about letting me add it as a reference to Test.dll, but not if I clean the solution first. It's just a pain to have to manually copy libtest.dll into the output directory of Test.dll each time libtest changes. But I suppose I can add a post-build event that can copy it over. I'll try adding it to the EXE project though and see if that works first.

Comment: Hmm, not so sure what the pain might be, but do make sure to *never* do it manually.  You'll forget when it is important.  "Copy if newer" never forgets.